# Firebase check if node exist return true or false

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have this firebase realtime database:
[image: Firebase tree]

I am making dating app, similar to tinder for my bachelor. I am creating match system now.

I created onCreate listener to check when the user presses like button and to check if another user already pressed like on current user. So this is what i tried.

```
exports.UserPressesLike = functions.database
  .ref('/users/{userId}/matches/{otherUserId}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    const original = snapshot.val();
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    const matchedUserId = context.params.otherUserId;
    const a = checkUserMatch(userId, matchedUserId);
    if (a === true) {
      console.log('Its a match');
    } else {
      console.log('There is no match');
      console.log(a);
    }

    return null;
  });

checkUserMatch = async (userId, matchedUserId) => {
  const snapshot = await admin
    .database()
    .ref('/users/' + matchedUserId + '/matches/' + userId)
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      // let tempuserId = snapshot.val();
      // if()
      return true;
    });
};
```

I want checkUserMatch to return true if there is that node, and false if there is no such node.

Comment: At the moment your question is really broad. Focus specifically on an issue you are having. What have you tried? What is it that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `checkUserMatch` is asynchronous (as shown by the fact you marked it with `async`), which means that it doesn't immediately return a value, but return an object that will eventually contain a value (a so-called promise).

To call an `async` function, you need to call it with `await`:

```
const a = await checkUserMatch(userId, matchedUserId);
```

This means that you also need to mark the function containing the call as `async`, so:

```
exports.UserPressesLike = functions.database
  .ref('/users/{userId}/matches/{otherUserId}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
```

Note that I highly recommend not continuing before you've learned more about asynchronous APIs, Promises and `async` / `await`. For example, by watching Doug's video series [Learn JavaScript Promises with HTTP Triggers in Cloud Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA).

Comment: Thanks, a lot, i googled about async/ await and after that saw your comment. Thanks for the content.

Answer (score 1):

After doing Puf's fix,  you can check if `snapshot.val() !== null`, or use the shortcut `snapshot.exists()`.

And you better rename your `const snapshot` to `const isLiked`, and then actually return that `isLiked` (or that function will return `undefined`).